# Setting up a VPN on Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: networking, vpn, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm having some issues getting a VPN to work as expected. I have a 2012R2 server at home. This acts as a public-facing web server, internal file server, and a few other things. I'm trying to have it function as a VPN server so I can access the SMB shares from elsewhere and so other clients can connect to my LAN over the internet for network gaming.

I've installed the Remote Access role, and set up a VPN on the server. All seems fine. I can connect to it externally and authenticate fine. The server status shows that the client is connected. This is where I run into issues. Once connected the client doesn't have access to the internet nor to the network resources. It appears they are provided with a local IP (from my router's DHCP server) however they are unable to so much as ping any network device.

Ideally I'd like to route the internet traffic through the VPN- or at least give clients the option to do so. I've been looking around the settings but can't seem to enable the VPN clients access to the LAN or the internet connection.

There are loads of things online, but people tend to end up split-tunneling at the client-side and that doesn't really solve my "no network resources" issue.

Anyone know of any typical issues that occur when setting up a VPN in this sort of way? Anything I've missed? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,
Dean

Answer (score 0):

I can only think of two things so far:

1. The firewall rules on the Windows Server 2012 R2. Are you using Windows firewall to do the VPN? Then are there any rules blocking the traffic from getting contact with the local network?
2. The second thing I can think of is the routing on the client. Perhaps the routing is not automatically configured and the traffic that is targeted for the remote servers are being routed to the local gateway? You can open the command prompt on the client and use `route print` to check the routing.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've tried completely disabling Windows Firewall on the server to no avail. I'm not too familiar with `route print` so am not sure how to interpret the result. One thing that is concerning me is that when I am connected to the VPN, an `ipconfig` on the client shows that the VPN adapter is offering a gateway of `0.0.0.0` and subnet of `255.255.255.255`. Surely that should be pointing to my router as gateway and should have a subnet of `255.255.255.0` to allow access to the other devices on that subnet?

Comment: [`route print` Output](http://pastebin.com/E9x7Ezup).

Comment: Thanks for the details. From what you pasted I guess `192.168.137.77` is your local client IP and `192.168.20.11` is your VPNed IP. I can see two default route one going through each subnets. The one on the `192.168.20.0` subnet seems to have lower metric so traffic will go there first. If `192.168.20.0` is indeed your VPN subnet then in theory you should at least be able to ping the servers in the VPN network. For internet access you might need a proxy in the VPN network to route the traffic to the correct place.